# Internationalization in JSF with xml files rather tan properties files

Tags: xml, jsf, internationalization

I would like to use xml files to work with internationalization in JavaServer Faces and not with properties files, because when I change or create a new text in properties files I need to restart the server for the changes take effect. or there is any different way to work with internationalization without the need of restart the server each time I need to create or modify a value?

Comment: Probably this is more related with a deploying tool rather than file types. Take a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9789483/1199132).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using XML based files instead of properties based files won't make any difference. It's ultimately still loaded and managed by the very same `ResourceBundle` API.

Best what you can try is to enable hot publishing and see if your particular combination of JRE, IDE, appserver and JSF implementation eats that. Don't forget to set JSF project stage to `Development`.

Here's how it look like in Eclipse+Tomcat after doubleclicking Tomcat server entry in *Servers* view:

[image]

---

> *because when I change or create a new text in properties files I need to restart the server for the changes take effect*

That's one of the (many) reasons why we use (and love) [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/).

#### See also:

- [Is it possible to apply changes to JSF files without republishing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280675/is-it-possible-to-apply-changes-to-jsf-files-without-republishing/)