# How can we create a dynamic web project in VS code?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, servlets

There is no option to create a new dynamic web project in vs code like eclipse. Is there is a way to do it like templates?

I tried to figure out but none helps

Comment: Visual Studio Code is not exactly an IDE. If you want that kind of automation use an actual IDE. Or generate a project with maven using artifacts and then import it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Is https://stackoverflow.com/a/74397713/19133920 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/74529380/19133920 useful?

Comment: Thanks for that ...But I need answer in seperate than comments to dismiss the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to install the [**Community Server Connectors**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-community-server-connector) extension.

[image]

Then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> --> `Servers: Add Local Servers...`.

[image]

In the pop-up explorer window, select the decompressed tomcat root directory (that is, the value of the system environment variable **CATALINA_HOME**).

[image]

Confirm that the information is correct and click `Finish`.

[image]

Select the generated `war` package, right-click and select `Run on Server`.

[image]

In the **SERVERS** view, right-click on the *tomcat* service and select `Server Actions...` --> `Show in browser...` --> `http://localhost:8080/demo/`.

[image]

The browser will open and display the project page.

[image]